# Error of displaying a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to display a JTable content issues that exist in the database when i click on "Afficher" it is a simple display but it did not work i didn't found the error

here is the result 
[image]

```
public class PreparerTestAutomatique extends JPanel
List<Question> questions;
JButton btnAfficher = new JButton("Afficher");
    btnAfficher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            categorie=GestionCategorieDelegate.doFindCategorieById(PreparerTest.idCategorie);
            if(Facile.getText().length()!=0){
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Facile.getText()), categorie,"Facile");
            } else{

            }
            if(Moyen.getText().length()!=0){
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Moyen.getText()), categorie, "Moyen");
            }else{

            }
            if(Difficile.getText().length()!=0){
                questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Difficile.getText()), categorie, "Difficile");
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

here is the method PrepareRandomTest it works very well I tested it

```
 @Override
public List<Question> prepareRandomTest(int number_of_questions, Categorie categorie, String niveauDeDifficulte){ 

          String jpql = "SELECT q FROM Question q where q.categorie=:categorie and q.niveauDeDifficulte=:niveauDeDifficulte ORDER BY RAND()";
          Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
          query.setParameter("categorie", categorie).setParameter("niveauDeDifficulte", niveauDeDifficulte);
          query.setMaxResults(number_of_questions);
          List<Question> result = query.getResultList();
          Collections.shuffle(result);
          return result;      
}
```

Comment: Start with [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Since you already have a `List` of objects, which I presume have properties, I would tend to learn towards starting with a `AbstractTableModel` as it allows you the greatest amount of flexibility without having decompose/recompose the object data

Comment: I read this document and I manipulated many tables but I do not know where is the problem @MadProgrammer

Comment: Well, no where in your code example do I see a `JTable` or `TableModel`

Comment: on the scrollPane i have a JTable i can't show you all the code because it's very long

Comment: And how is your code interacting with it?  And some point you need to build a `TableModel` of some kind which encapsulates your data and apply it the `JTable` that's on the screen

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry but can you explain more i can not applicate my exemple with TableModel . I create a simple JTable who contains a list of Questions and i display with "PrepareRandomTest" i didn't  understand howa to applicate it on my exemple please help me